# dropdown changes depending on another dropdown

Tags: java, spring-mvc, enums

I'm using spring mvc. One dropdown X is based on enum. I want to change the dropdown Y list based on dropdown X. What should I do for the second dropdown Y. Should I use enum? The list won't be changing very often so I am not planning to use database. I want to know the good practice.

Even if I use enum. How do I define that this variable should produce this list.

Answer (score 1):

In my practice I have used this kind of scenario. You can define Y list also an enumeration. Cause enumerations are classes You can implement dependency behavior between enumeration constants, depending on which relationships they have between them (I mean one-to-many, many-to-many, ...), You can initialize the particular X constant by providing Y constants list via X constructor.

For example in many-to-many relation You can use the following strategy

```
enum X{
    A("1", "A", Y.D, Y.E),
    B("2", "B", Y.D, Y.F),
    C("3", "C", Y.D, Y.E, Y.F);

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Y> dependencies = new ArrayList<Y>();

    private X(String id, String name, Y... dependencies){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

        for(Y dep : dependencies){
            this.dependencies.add(dep);
        }
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Y> getDependencies(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(dependencies);
    }
}

enum Y{
    D(),
    E(),
    F();

    private Y(){}
}
```